# Configure Nifi to use SSO for wso2 IS

Tags: wso2, apache-nifi, wso2-identity-server

How do I configure Apache NiFi to use SSO in wso2 IS? I already have a password authentication enabled independently for NiFi. Now I am trying to integrate WSO2 IS for SSO. Couldn't find much help in the help pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following guide to create a OIDC servive provider in IS for Nifi. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/login/sso-for-oidc/

I was able to find a resource for Nifi which integrates with Google through OIDC. https://bryanbende.com/development/2017/10/03/apache-nifi-openid-connect

You can use both resources to configure Nifi to use SSO with WSO2 IS.